connexion datasynapse openshift
I have an openshift cluster, and API deployed in openshift, the api should call datasynapse engine.
when I set DSDirectDataTransfer  to false, the communication between the pod and datasynapse work perfectly,
however, when I set it to true, I got error:
Task failed after 1 retries. last failed due to: org.apache.http.com.HttpHostConnectionException: connection to 10.2.30.x failed: connection timed out...
I should set the flag to true, but this not work.
Any idea to resolve this issue?
